# java.util.Pattern matches only one alternative group?

Tags: java, regex

Say for instance you had a `java.util.Pattern` compiled with multiple alternatives, each a capture group:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(a?bc)|(ab?c)|(abc?)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("abc");
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
```

You will see:

```
true
abc
null
null
```

Is there a way to get each of these capture groups to match, or are you always going to be restricted to a single matching group?

That is, since "abc" matches each of the alternatives above, is there any way to get this as output:

```
true
abc
abc
abc
```

I'm guessing not, given what I remember about implementation of regular expressions, but I thought I'd check.

Comment: it can't be possible when the patterns are seperated by logical OR operator.

Answer (score 3):

Using alternation it will populate only one group out of many but you can use lookaheads to populate all 3 groups you want:

```
(?=(a?bc))(?=(ab?c))(?=(abc?))
```

It will populate `abc` in all 3 groups as you want.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vC2hD3/1)

#### [Java Code Demo](http://ideone.com/lUPhl6)

**Update:** Also you need to use `Matcher#find()` in order to get multiple matches:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=(a?bc))(?=(ab?c))(?=(abc?))");
Matcher m = p.matcher("abc");
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.printf("%s::<%s> <%s> <%s>%n", m.group(), m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3));
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work with the code above. I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found on first group()

Comment: You're using find instead of matches. Please make it part of your answer then.

Comment: find() will match against a substring, though, which isn't the same behavior as matches().

For instance, try using "abcdef" as your example string. This won't match anything in the example I gave above, but will match all of them here.

Comment: Also to remove some confusion around `find` vs `matches` **[I have created another code demo](http://ideone.com/lUPhl6)** for you where you can clearly see this approach works for `matches` also.

Comment: Actually, no, it doesn't. As I said above, if you replace the example string with "abcdef", it produces "abc" as matches, which isn't correct.  http://ideone.com/6Cvnhb

Comment: Thanks for coming back after so long. Yes `Matcher.matches() ` will return `true` for matching whole string and that is happening due to use of `.*` at the end of our regex.

Comment: Sorry, the word "match" is overloaded here somewhat. By "matches", I meant Matcher.matches() which operates on the entire string as distinct from "find" which operates on a substring. I wanted to match the entire string against the pattern. From that perspective, "abc" would match but "abcdef" would not.

Comment: ok so for the above example you want no output if input string is `abcdef` but all 3 groups if input is `abc` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that, logically, you are better off putting all of the alternatives in a single capture group, such as `(a?bc|ab?c|abc?)`, so that you capture the matched string into the first group if and only if it matches one of your alternatives.

If you want to specify different behavior based on which alternatives match, you will have to examine each of the three capturing groups in turn anyway (and compare them to null), so you are just as well off saying

```
if (str.matches("a?bc")) ... 
else if (str.matches("ab?c")) ... 
else if (str.matches("abc?")) ...
else ... // no match
```

or

```
if (str.matches("a?bc")) ... 
if (str.matches("ab?c")) ... 
if (str.matches("abc?")) ...
```

Comment: That's not really very efficient, though, as it's matching separately against N separately-compiled regular expressions. Merging the regular expressions together allows the resulting finite automaton to share common states.

Comment: Who said that java uses automatons to model regular expressions... http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html. And I doubt that the lookaheads are particularly efficient, either.  I think it would be easier to understand your query if you explained your use case more.